# Where should I ask my question about an electromagnetic charger?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469089/why-does-this-magnetic-charger-cause-short-circuit-when-it-sticks-to-the-metal-l) about some electrical gadgets.
I first tried to ask it in Physics.SE, but it was migrated to ElectricalEngineering.SE, and then locked there.

Now, I have still no answer to my question. What is the proper site for this question?

Comment: Good thing those that voted for migration know what is on-topic on the target site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a generic [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) site which might help you out. Searching the site gives quite a few questions about chargers and short-circuiting, but please check their [Help Center](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first to make sure your question is well-received there.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted my question there.